# How do I get location info from http response?

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

I understand [what location does in HTTP headers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-location/).

Access to a [site](https://ec.ef.com.cn/partner/englishcenters) with Chrome gets `location` in response headers.

[image]

However, access to it with Python requests cannot get that info.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.5',
}
response = requests.get('https://ec.ef.com.cn/partner/englishcenters', headers=headers)
response.headers
```

Does it matter for scrapy? How do I get that info? Because I guess it might be a flag the site could use for anti-scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in your screenshot is response with [HTTP code 302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) which will usually automatically redirect some clients (along with [Python Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)) to another URL, specified in `Location` header.

If you enter the URL you shared (`https://ec.ef.com.cn/partner/englishcenters`) in your browser, you'll see you will get redirected to some other URL. Same behaviour can be observed in your Python code if you print out [`response.url`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.url) which should return you the URL you've been redirected to.

Comment: Thank you. Does "along with Python Requests" mean Python Requests could redirect automatically? Do I need to add coding like `requests.get(response.url)` manually?

Comment: Check out the [Python Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) link, it's explained there - "By default Requests will perform location redirection for all verbs except HEAD." And if you will need to access the history of redirections (since there can be multiple ones), you can get them from [`response.history`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.history) as mentioned in that first link too :)